# How to apply a SAN SSL Certificate to multiple subdomains on a single IP (Same Server) in Apache Web Server on Windows

Tags: windows, apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, virtualhost

I have a SAN SSL Certificate which covers about 4 subdomains. Os is windows.

```
abc.mydomain.com
xyz.mydomain.com
pqr.mydomain.com
jkl.mydomain.com
```

The common name for the certificate is **abc.mydomain.com**

How can I apply this certificate in Apache so that it could provide SSL security to all the four domains. I mean how should I configure Apache in this case.

Comment: Can someone help me here ?